# How can I make a page with css,which the background image is cover , with scrolling and also responsive?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a page,which by scroll down ,the content div ,cover the back ground image.so I put a background image for body and create 2 divs, it works in big window size, but when I change the size of window, and make it smaller (to test the responsive), there is a white gap between image and content div.

Would you please help me to remove it?

```
       <html>
        <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                <title>first</title>

                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
                <link href="css/first.css"  rel="stylesheet">

        <style>

        body{

            background: url("https://kalamarie123.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/img_7815-2.jpg") no-repeat top center fixed;
            background-size:100%;


        }


        </style>
        </head>


        <body>

        <div class="cover"></div>
        <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of </div>   

        </body>
        </html>



.cover{
    height: 1232px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;

}
.content{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: gray;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: What image? There's no image in your demo code so we can't see a gap between it and anything else.

Comment: body{

    background: url("img/crop.jpg") no-repeat top center fixed;
    background-size:100%;
   
  
}

Comment: Please **edit** the test case to provide a working demonstration of the problem (and an image we can actually access, your relative URL doesn't do us much good).

Comment: I add css code for body, but the demo doesnt work .let me test one more time.

Comment: "and an image we can actually access, your relative URL doesn't do us much good" … because Stackoverflow isn't hosting anything at that URL.

Comment: how I can add my background image here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the body and the html go to the bottom of the page:

```
body, html {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

and then set the background to `background-size: cover;`: https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: thanks,but when I change to this code,my image is not responsive.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
<div id="yourdiv"></div>

#yourdiv {
width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0;
background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center top; position: fixed; z-index: -1;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's probably due to your background image not filling the full space available.

Try adding this to the body (the element with the BG image);

```
background-size:cover;
```

Note that this will not work well on old browsers

Comment: thanks,but when I change to this code,my image is not responsive.

Comment: Not responsive? Cover makes the image fill the containers height and width, it should still respond. Are you using an old browser like IE8?

I tested the principal in modern Chrome and Firefox with no issues.

Comment: I try on google chrome and firefox,the gap is remove but both of them not responsive.do you know how I can add my background image here,which will show in demo?

Comment: Ok, can you explain how it's not "Responsive" and what you're expecting it to do?